# Jquery Does not submit the form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Here is my form

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="ProductReg">
       <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                   <div class="sub-title">Name of Product</div>
                   <div><input type="text" name="ProductName" class="form-  control" placeholder="This field is required" required>
                   </div>
              </div>
                  <div><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="submit" Value="Register" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPrimary"></div>
          </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

And Here is the modal Which triggers when I Click The Above input Button

```
<div class="modal fade modal-primary" id="modalPrimary" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Product Registration</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Do You Really Want To Register This Product????
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            <button type="button" id="SumitTheForm" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I Click The Modals' No Button It cancels but the thing which I want is TO SUBMIT THE FORM WHEN I CLICK THE MODALs' YES BUTTON 
I Tried This By using jquery But It didn't work

```
$('#SumitTheForm').click(function() {
    $('#ProductReg').submit();
});
```

NOTE: I placed the modal at the end of my document, even After The script links (I think It is The right place, If not tell me plzz)

Comment: _NOTE: I placed the modal at the end of my document, even After The script links_. --> The "SubmitTheForm" element isn't found because you are doing this

Comment: Try javascript? document.getElementById("ProductReg").submit();

Comment: Your jQuery is probably not wrapped in the document ready function. Try wrapping your jQuery code like so... $(function () { [code goes here] });

Comment: I added The ready function but Still didn't work @mhodges

Comment: add alerts or console.log() in the click function before and after the .submit() call to do a little debugging.  See if it even calls the click function.  See if the submit() fails and it doesn't even get to end of click function.  Also did you look in the developer tools console to see if there are any errors being spit out?  Also this shouldn't be causing a problem but scripts should be the very end of document, so modal should go before that.

Comment: When I use javascript the console issues This Error "document.getElementById(...).submit() is not a function" but when I use Jquery The alerts   After and before submit function is being shown but the form doesnt being sumbited and the console doen't show any error @gimbel0893

Answer (score 3):

As per my comment. Try wrapping your jQuery code in the document ready function. This makes sure to wait until the DOM is loaded before trying to bind events handlers to elements. Not doing this can cause issues because if the javascript tries to bind the event to an element before it exists, it will not work.

```
$(function () {
  $("#SubmitTheForm").on("click", function () {
    $("#ProductReg").submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried, but didn't work, Still Button doesn't do anything @mhodges

Comment: are you entering the click event? that is, if you place an alert or console.log() inside of the click handler for #SubmitTheForm, does that code execute?

Answer (score 0):

Use document ready :

```
$('document').ready(fucntion(){
     $('#SumitTheForm').click(function() {
         $('#ProductReg').submit();
     });
});
```

Or you can try AJAX for submitting your data .

Answer (score 0):

You can atatch the event to the document, so you dont need to wait for the document is ready.

```
$(document).on('click', '#SumitTheForm', function() {
  $('#ProductReg').submit();
});
```

Comment: Still Didn't work man, Actually It Refreshes the page but does not submit my form